# DjangoQ run manage.py qcluster results in PermissionError: [WinError5] Access is denied

Tags: python, django, celery

I've just recently started played around with web application development using Django and now got to Django-Q for async tasks.

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.liang2.tw/2016Talk-Django-Q/#) up to slide 13. Unfortunately then, when I try to run `python manage.py qcluster` I get these error messages:

```
(djangoq_tut) D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_demo>python manage.py qcluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django_q\management\commands\qcluster.py", line 22, in handle
    q.start()
  File "D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_tut\lib\site-packages\django_q\cluster.py", line 57, in start
    self.sentinel.start()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

(djangoq_tut) D:\Code\Python\DjangoQ_Tutorial\djangoq_demo>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 100, in spawn_main
    new_handle = steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 86, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I'm using a Windows 7 machine and Python 3.5.1 (32 bit) with following requirements:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
arrow==0.10.0
blessed==1.14.1
Django==1.9
django-picklefield==0.3.2
django-q==0.7.18
future==0.16.0
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
six==1.10.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

I tried looking up the source of the error, it looks to me as it might not be exclusively related to Django or Django-Q. Other than that I don't really understand what it means.

Also tried with Python 2.7.12, outside of a virtualenv, there I get a `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`, which I don't really get either.

Any ideas how to solve this?

[Edit]
After experimenting with a DjangoQ alternative - Celery - I as able to recreate the problem:
The same error occurs if using Celery 4.0.2, but not with Celery 3.1.25
I still haven't figured out how to fix this, but decided to stick to Celery for the time being, since it kinda works...

Answer (score 0):

```
Install the latest version with pip:

$ pip install django-q

Add django_q to INSTALLED_APPS in your projects settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # other apps
    'django_q',
)

Run Django migrations to create the database tables:

$ python manage.py migrate

Choose a message broker , configure it and install the appropriate client library.

Run Django Q cluster in order to handle tasks async:

$ python manage.py qcluster
```